# Open .xlsm file from desktop straight to Excel Online

Tags: microsoft-excel

So this may be more of a programming or scripting question, but here's my situation. I have my computer desktop synced up with OneDrive, having all my files accessible from file explorer, Cortana search, etc. I don't use my computer enough to justify getting Microsoft Office but I still use excel/word occasionally. My question is this: Is there a way to open these types of files directly into Microsoft Office Online (the web apps)? The current behavior is when I click on the file, windows asks me what program I want to use to open it because I don't have any spreadsheet editor downloaded on my computer. But I wanted to know if there was some way to tell the browser to open directly to Office Online to edit it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the workaround workflow would be to view oneDrive from your web browser, then when you click on an excel file it will open the web version for you to manipulate.

Comment: I know that's the normal way that should happen, but being lazy I wanted to see if I could open it straight into that website.